# Error opening Eclipse "Registry Key"

Tags: java, eclipse, registry

I get these erros when I try to open Eclipse:

Error opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment' 
Error: could not find Java.dll 
Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment

I updated java like 2 days ago. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Java, reinstall. Maybe the update broke something? Also check your environment variables for Java are good. Need help with the environment variables? well a search engine is your friend.

Are you running on XP? Windows 7, Mac Linux??